# Python 2.7 - use waitKeys to capture user input (string) of a specified length

Tags: python-2.7

***Please note I am a novice trying to learn***

I've searched for ages, but haven't found an answer to my problem.
Basically, I'm displaying a number of alphabetical characters on a screen. The number of character increases in increments (5, 7, 9).
What I need is to have the loop pause and wait for the user to input the characters they've just seen, but so far, the code I have only seems to allow the user to input ONE character (or keypress), and I can't figure out how to make it keep waiting until a specified number of characters has been entered by the user.  My code is below:

```
letter5.draw()
win.flip()
respClock.reset()
core.wait(info['letterTime'])

win.flip()

#wait for response
respList = waitKeys(maxWait = float('inf'), keyList = letters)
keys = respList [0]
```

I think a while loop may work here, but I've not managed to come up with a piece of code that works properly.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out on my own and thought I'd share:

```
resp = ''
done = False
while len(resp) < 4:
    respList = waitKeys(maxWait = float('inf'), keyList = alpha)
    key = respList[0]

    if len(key) == 1:
        resp += key
    elif key == 'space':
        resp += ''
    elif key == 'backspace' and len(resp) > 0:
        resp = resp[0:-1]
    if key == 'return':
        done = True
```